# XML Parsing from a response of Invoke-WebRequest

Tags: xml, powershell

I am trying to parse a specific value from a response to an `Invoke-WebRequest` I have made in a PowerShell script, but I am not able to get it.

If I used postman for example to get the content I would get the below:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<globalInfo>
    <currentLoggedInUser>admin</currentLoggedInUser>
    <versionInfo>
        <majorVersion>6</majorVersion>
        <minorVersion>2</minorVersion>
        <patchVersion>4</patchVersion>
        <buildNumber>4292526</buildNumber>  <!-- this is what I need -->
    </versionInfo>
</globalInfo>
```

Below is the command I am using within the script and I get nothing:

```bsh
$r = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "$uriP/api/1.0/appliance-management/global/info" -Body $body -Method:Get -Headers $head -ContentType "application/xml" -ErrorAction:Stop -TimeoutSec 60
$bn = ($r.Content.globalInfo.versionInfo.buildNumber)
```

Also, if I used `$bn = ($r.Content)` I will get the full content like below:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<globalInfo><currentLoggedInUser>admin</currentLoggedInUser><versionInfo><majorVersion>6</majorVersion><minorVersion>2</minorVersion><patchVersion>4</patch
Version><buildNumber>4292526</buildNumber></versionInfo></globalInfo>
```

I can see the format of the response from the postman is different from the one I get in PowerShell using only (`$r.Content`), but I am not sure what is the issue here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$r.Content` is a string. You need to actually parse the XML in it before you can access the individual nodes:

```
$bn = ([xml]$r.Content).globalInfo.versionInfo.buildNumber
```

Comment: Ansgar, Thank you so much for your help. This works fine now.

Comment: this not work for me for some reason, I get error saying the specified node cannot be inserted as the valid child of this node, because the specified node is the wrong type - any advice?

Comment: @GorodeckijDimitrij The code I posted doesn't insert anything anywhere. Please post a new question with your code, sample input, and the actual error message.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers I use exactly your code, provide error that return by powershell